# Angular - Unable to use "scrollPositionRestoration"

Tags: angular

I am currently using Angular 6.1.5. When the website is routed to a different page, I would like for the page to be scroll back to the top. I tried using `{ scrollPositionRestoration: 'top' }` but it does not work.

Here's my code in app.routing.ts.

```
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'top' });
```

Is there an alternative to this? I tried changing from 'top' to enabled' but it does not work as well. I also tried `window.scrollTo(0,0);` and placed it in `ngOnInit()` but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 8):

In my case didn't work because I had this on my CSS.

```
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  :root {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
}
```

I changed to

```
scroll-behavior: auto;
```

And then it starts working

Comment: Great work. scroll-behavior: auto; will work in firefox also.

Comment: This perfectly works in safari. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Update the options in your code to provide it with a `scrollOffset` as well.

```
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { scrollOffset: [0, 0], scrollPositionRestoration: 'top' });
```

Another option would be to do it more 'manually'. Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bckul2) demonstrating this approach. Basically in the entry component for the application(or the entry component for the area of your application with the forms) you could subscribe to the router events and on `NavigationEnd` you can use `window.scrollTo`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Event, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(
    router: Router
  ) {
    router.events
          .pipe(filter((routerEvent: Event) => routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd))
          .subscribe(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0));
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, it didnt work. pages wont be scrolled back to the top. tried scrollPositionRestoration: enabled as well

Comment: @mhfour You are going to need to provide more details about what you are doing then. Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bckul2) demonstrating that the above does work.

Comment: @peinarydevelopment i've also heard from plenty of others that have stated that there are still issues with scrollPositionRestoration. i basically have pages with very long forms. when the user clicks on save at the bottom of the form, he/she should be directed to the top of the next form

Comment: @mhfour I have updated my answer with an alternative approach. Unfortunately your question and comments don't really help lead you to a solution. I have demonstrated that `scrollPositionRestoration` can work and you haven't given any details about when/where it doesn't work. Hope the alternative approach will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using router-outlet, it is possible that the components element are of size 0x0.
By adding a CSS rule on app-root to display block, made `scrollPositionRestoration` work:

```
app-root {
   display: block;
}

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { scrollOffset: [0, 0], scrollPositionRestoration: 'top' });
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that works for me on Angular 10.2.x is using setTimeout for 190ms and no less! If I set timer below 190ms, scrolling is not work!

When I set the timer to 300ms, then I can see how, after routing, the page first scrolls to a position I don't need, and then page scrolls to 0, as it should. I still do not understand what process in Angular makes unnecessary scrolling after route to the page.

I tried different suggested solutions. For example, such as changing the value of the scrollPositionRestoration property and performing forced scrolling in the AfterViewInit hook, and changing the global height of body tag and using (activate) on router outlet and many others, but only this helped. Most likely this is some kind of error in the Angular 10.2.x router

```
constructor(
  private router: Router,
) {
  router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // || window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, 190);
  }
}
```